# I'm executing Pipeline in Pymongo aggregate but collection doesn't show any changes

Tags: python, mongodb

Dears,

This is my pipeline which ends with merge, it works smooth on Mongo compass but when it comes to be executed by using PyMongo it doesn't work

```html
migrate_students_documents = [
    {
        '$set': {
            'science_sections_act': [
                'Science'
            ],
            'english_sections_act': [
                'Section 1: English Sitting 1', 'Section 2: English Sitting 2'
            ],
            'math_sections_act': [
                'Section 4: Math Sitting 1', 'Section 5: Math Sitting 2'
            ],
            'reading_sections_act': [
                'Section 3: Reading'
            ]
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {}
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$sections'
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$scaled_scores_act'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': [
                {
                    'oid': '$_id'
                }, {
                    'course_id': '$sections.course_id'
                }
            ],
            'sections': {
                '$push': '$sections'
            },
            'scaled_scores_act_placement': {
                '$mergeObjects': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$scaled_scores_act.session_type', 0
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': {
                            'english': '$scaled_scores_act.english',
                            'math': '$scaled_scores_act.math',
                            'reading': '$scaled_scores_act.reading',
                            'science': '$scaled_scores_act.science'
                        },
                        'else': '$$REMOVE'
                    }
                }
            },
            'scaled_scores_act_exit': {
                '$mergeObjects': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$eq': [
                                '$scaled_scores_act.session_type', 2
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': {
                            'english': '$scaled_scores_act.english',
                            'math': '$scaled_scores_act.math',
                            'reading': '$scaled_scores_act.reading',
                            'science': '$scaled_scores_act.science'
                        },
                        'else': '$$REMOVE'
                    }
                }
            },
            'science_answered_count_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$science_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.answered_count',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'english_answered_count_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$english_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.answered_count',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'math_answered_count_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$math_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.answered_count',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'reading_answered_count_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$reading_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.answered_count',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'science_total_questions_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$science_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.total_questions',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'english_total_questions_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$english_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.total_questions',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'math_total_questions_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$math_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.total_questions',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'reading_total_questions_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$reading_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.total_questions',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'science_correct_answers_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$science_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.correct_answers',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'english_correct_answers_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$english_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.correct_answers',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'math_correct_answers_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$math_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.correct_answers',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            'reading_correct_answers_placement': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': {
                        'if': {
                            '$and': [
                                {
                                    '$in': [
                                        '$sections.section_name', '$reading_sections_act'
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$sections.session_type', 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        'then': '$sections.correct_answers',
                        'else': 0
                    }
                }
            },

        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'stats': {
                'district_id': {
                    '$first': '$sections.district_id'
                },
                'district_name': {
                    '$first': '$sections.district_name'
                },
                'course_id': {
                    '$first': '$sections.course_id'
                },
                'course_name': {
                    '$first': '$sections.course_name'
                },
                'course_curriculum': {
                    '$first': '$sections.course_curriculum'
                },
                'placement': {
                    'section_score': {
                        'english': {
                            'answered_count': '$english_answered_count_placement',
                            'total_questions': '$english_total_questions_placement',
                            'correct_answers': '$english_correct_answers_placement',
                            'percent_of_completion': {
                                '$cond': [
                                    {
                                        '$eq': [
                                            '$english_total_questions_placement', 0
                                        ]
                                    }, 0, {
                                        '$divide': [
                                            '$english_answered_count_placement', '$english_total_questions_placement'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        'math': {
                            'answered_count': '$math_answered_count_placement',
                            'total_questions': '$math_total_questions_placement',
                            'correct_answers': '$math_correct_answers_placement',
                            'percent_of_completion': {
                                '$cond': [
                                    {
                                        '$eq': [
                                            '$math_total_questions_placement', 0
                                        ]
                                    }, 0, {
                                        '$divide': [
                                            '$math_answered_count_placement', '$math_total_questions_placement'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        'reading': {
                            'answered_count': '$reading_answered_count_placement',
                            'total_questions': '$reading_total_questions_placement',
                            'correct_answers': '$reading_correct_answers_placement',
                            'percent_of_completion': {
                                '$cond': [
                                    {
                                        '$eq': [
                                            '$reading_total_questions_placement', 0
                                        ]
                                    }, 0, {
                                        '$divide': [
                                            '$reading_answered_count_placement', '$reading_total_questions_placement'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        'science': {
                            'answered_count': '$science_answered_count_placement',
                            'total_questions': '$science_total_questions_placement',
                            'correct_answers': '$science_correct_answers_placement',
                            'percent_of_completion': {
                                '$cond': [
                                    {
                                        '$eq': [
                                            '$science_total_questions_placement', 0
                                        ]
                                    }, 0, {
                                        '$divide': [
                                            '$science_answered_count_placement', '$science_total_questions_placement'
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'scaled_score': '$scaled_scores_act_placement'
                },
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                '$first': '$_id.oid'
            },
            'stats': {
                '$addToSet': '$stats'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'id': 1,
            'stats': 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        '$merge': {
            'into': 'students',
            'on': '_id'
        }
    }
]
```

Pymongo doesn't show errors when executing mongo.chalktalk.command('aggregate', 'students', pipeline=migrate_students_documents, explain=True) but nothing is changed on collection

Comment: Need to include your code in the question.

Comment: Any using of $merge with aggregation in pymongo won't work

Comment: why there is a `'$match': {}` stage? It should pick up no record

Comment: when match is empty will get everything, this query is verified against mongo compass and it works successfully. Just inside PyMongo it doesn't (merge stage won't work)

Comment: "_when match is empty will get everything_" -> yes, but that's the default behavior (AKA without a `$match` stage at all).  But anyway, I came here to ask something else. Is the intent of this operation to calculate and save some summary stats per document? If you provide a sample before and after document, I am pretty sure that this can be done via an `update()` directly without unwinding, grouping, and merging

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using command to aggregate, use this below for the same pipeline

```
students = chalktalk.students.aggregate(migrate_students_documents)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.